# How to use a reactive dataset while exporting datatable to csv from Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to export a reactive datatable to csv in my Shiny app but seem to be running into an error where the app can't find the function that creates the reactive dataset while downloading it but seems to render it fine in the app.

The code I have for this is as follows:

```
ui <- 
  fluidRow(
    column(3, style = "padding:10px",
           downloadButton("downloadData", "Export current table to Excel")
    )
  ),
DT::dataTableOutput("customertable")

server <- function(input,output,session){
  dataExpTable <- reactive({
    all_statesClean %>%
      filter(
        is.null(input$states) | ship_to_region %in% input$states,
        is.null(input$counties) | county %in% input$counties,
        as.numeric(gsub(",", "", avg_opioid)) >= input$custminopVol,
        as.numeric(gsub(",", "", avg_opioid_perc)) >= input$custminopp,
        as.numeric(gsub(",", "", avg_oxy_hydro_perc)) >= -1,
        as.numeric(gsub(",", "", avg_oxy_hydro)) >= 0,
        c_avg_opioid >= input$minopVol,
        c_avg_opioid_perc >= input$minopp,
        c_avg_opioid_ppp >= input$minopppp,
        c_avg_oxy_hydro_perc >= -1,
        c_avg_oxy_hydro >= 0,
        c_avg_oxy_hydro_ppp >= 0
      )
  })

  output$customertable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      dataExpTable(),
      escape = FALSE
    )
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

    filename = function(){
      paste(gsub("-", ".", Sys.Date()), " - ", "County level"," data",".csv", sep = "")
    }

    content = function(file){
      write.csv(dataExpTable(),file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}
```

Instead of getting a csv file out of this, the download button just prints an HTML version of the entire page and returns the error:

`Error in is.data.frame(x) : could not find function "dataExpTable"`

Answer (score 0):

Was just missing a comma after the `filename` function.